# Comma question "ob ... gilt, ..."

Tags: comma

Would one put the bold comma or not:

> Die Frage, ob ... gilt**,** darf man nur stellen, wenn ...

Without the comma the sentence doesn't read good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Die Frage darf man nur stellen ..

is interrupted by

> ob ... gilt

and such an embedded clause needs to be separated by commas.

So

> Die Frage, ob ... gilt, darf man nur stellen, wenn ...

is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: Reference to Rechtschreibregeln, § 74, could be added: "Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein."

Answer (score 3):

`ob ... gilt` is a relative subordinate clause (Relativsatz/Nebensatz). It relates to the surrounding sentence: it further explains which `Frage` the rest of the sentence refers to.

As such, it needs to be surrounded by commas. See [Duden D118](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#D118) and §74 (on page 81) of the [official rules (released 2018, PDF)](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf) ([online version](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par74)) based on the 2016 recommendations of the council for german spelling. Both sources are in german.

---

Subordinate clauses can be identified easily: if you drop out everything between the commas, it should still read as a valid sentence (that may provide less information though). `Die Frage darf man nur stellen, wenn ...` is valid, hence you need commas when inserting a subordinate clause.

Another example: `Die Frage darf man, selbst als Geschäftsführer, nur stellen, wenn ...` This subordinate clause indicates that even a CEO may only ask this question, when ... This construct sort of indicates that the sentence is about a very special or tricky question (which not even a CEO may simply ask), even though the subordinate clause is not placed next to `Frage`.

Comment: Thanks also to you! :-)

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. Do you think there is a useful webpage for further reading that you can cite about that rule?

Comment: Sure, I added two sources (Duden and official rules). However, both are in german. I didn't find any english sources.